# TFS Custom Project Alerts

Tags: alert, tfs-workitem, team-project

I have a problem configurating my TFS 2010.
My problem is that the default "Project Alerts" in Team Web Access aren't enough to match our requirements. We need  more detailed alerts.

So my question is:
How can I create an alert-template as shown in the list of the "Project Alerts" (Visual Studio -> Team -> Project Alerts), which is accessible for all users (also through Web Access) without installing TFS Power Tools.

regards

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe that's possible (at least not easily possible, you might be able to do something with a web access extension to expose a custom control outside of the standard Project Alerts functionality).

However, you can use the Power Tools to subscribe people other than yourself to alerts if you wish.  Not ideal, but usually sufficient.

Of course anybody can install Team Explorer + Power Tools and create their own Alerts also using the Alert Explorer.